# How to stop WinDbg from shrinking its windows?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

It's kind a weird bug. Say, if I open a `WinDbg` and position all windows the way I prefer to work in it:

[image]

Then, for some reason, the more I open `WinDbg` the more it shrinks all of those windows. So over time it all ends up looking like this:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent it from doing it?

Comment: On a modern Windows machine, you might try its latest preview, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools which should work better with HDPI and so on.

Comment: @LexLi: Yeah. Thanks. Unfortunately it's Win10 only.

Comment: no, the [preview runs also on older Windows versions](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0bx90y7onucw48e/Microsoft.WinDbg_1.1805.17002.0.png?dl=1) with .net 4.6.1. Get the appx link via HTTP proxy on a Win10 system and expand the appx with a zip tool and run it on every syste myou want

Comment: does the new preview work the way you need it? I haven't used it very much. I'll look at it when it reaches RTM status.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a fix for the old version of WinDbg. This is how you can install WinDbg Preview v.10 on a Windows system other than 10. (Suggested by @magicandre1981 in the comments to my original question.)

- Install [WinDbg Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windbg-preview/9pgjgd53tn86) from the Windows Store on a Windows 10 machine. Then run it.
- Open Task Manager and switch to the `Processes` tab. Locate `WinDbg Preview` and click  the left chevron to open it:

[image]

- Right-click `DbgX.Shell.exe` and select "Open file location". This will open it in Windows Explorer.

  In my case the folder was:

  `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinDbg_1.1808.20001.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe`
- Close WinDbg Preview app.
- Select all files in the opened folder and copy them to a destination Windows machine. (I've done this on a Windows 8.1 machine, but supposedly it can also run on Windows 7 as long as the right version of .NET Framework is installed. According to magicandre1981 it should be .NET 4.6.1. I didn't test it though.)
- Move all WinDbg Preview files into a `Program Files` folder on a target machine. Then run `DbgX.Shell.exe` in it to start WinDbg Preview:

[image]

Or you may want to make a shortcut for it and place it on your taskbar.

---

I personally like WinDbg Preview better than the old version of WinDbg. True, it has some of its own bugs. But the good thing is that they constantly update it, i.e. develop it.

Here are some quick screenshots of how it looks like (as for today, Sept. 2, 2018):

- This is how you can attach to a VM for kernel debugging (via a virtual COM port) which is still slow, but manageable for a short debugging session. The main point is that the debugger is much more user-friendly. In this case all you need to do is click OK to connect. It remembered all my previous settings:

[image]

- And this is how my customized debugging environment looks like:

[image]

As you can see, a much improved disassembly screen, locals and watch windows, stack trace, memory dump, etc. Yes, the command bar on the top takes too much space, but one can fold it up if they prefer to operate WinDbg via command line. I personally, as you can see, don't use command window, I like mashing buttons with a mouse :)

And, by the way, make sure to check for updates regularly on a Windows 10 machine and repeat the steps above to install WinDbg Preview. (Unfortunately there's no way to update  it from a non-Windows 10 computer.) In my experience for a few months that I've been using it, they released multiple updates and fixed the most glaring bugs.

Although quite a few bugs still remain ...